# Applescript - Idein

Tags: applescript

I'm newbie to Appplescript. I need to automate certain actions on my computer related with my Bluetooth keyboards.

I want to be able to click on the remove or connect button of a keyboard in the following dialog window of the System Preferences Panel.

[Dialog window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55dPZ.jpg)

My code until this moment is as follows:

```
try
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click button "Set Up Bluetooth Keyboard…" of window "Keyboard"
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
        click button "remove" of "Home Keyboard"
    end tell
end tell
end try
```

My problem is related with the remove button since is unidentified cell of an unidentified table. With unidentified, I mean without description. Maybe there is an easy solution, but I'm not able to find it. Furthermore, It could happen that more than one keyboard exists, so I need to identify the cell from the Keyboard name.

Do you know any hint related with this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if GUI element have no name you can still access to them by using their number like 'button 3 of pane 1 of window 1'. It should also be loop through UI elements to check value of static text 1 of that element. . I don't have bluetooth keyboard, but this is what I do to find my mouse

Comment: Could you provide an example if it is easy for you from your mouse management automatization? Thank you  in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a sample script I used to reconnect a specific mouse via Bluetooth :

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        reveal anchor "MouseTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.mouse"
    end tell
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        click button "Configuration of Bluetooth mouse…" of window 1 -- see note 1
        delay 1
        select (first row of table 1 of scroll area 1 of sheet 1 of front window whose value of item 1 of static text of UI element 1 contains "Mouse") -- see note 1
        get value of item 1 of static text of UI element 1 of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of sheet 1 of front window
        click button "Done" of sheet 1 of front window -- see note 1
    end tell
    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
end tell
```

Note 1 : Be careful about the 3 lines with comment 'see note 1' : the value of the string may be different for your local language. Please adjust these 3 values.

I think for keyboard, concept should be very similar. Because it is using GUI scripting, if Apple changes the layout of Bluetooth screen preferences, it must be adjusted. This script works from Yosemite to ElCaptain.I can't test it for next systems.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it ASAP I will have a free slot.